# Custom emacs nxml indentation

Tags: emacs, indentation

For the last 3 years, my work required writing and editing configuration files in xml format. The content in the xml tags has evolved so much that now it has become kind of like a programming language. Unfortunately, emacs indents everything inside the tags at the same level. Something like this:

[image: current emacs indentation in nxml mode]

But it'd be wicked if I could get the content indented like the following:

[image: how I wish emacs would ident it]

I've read several threads related to custom indentation, but I still don't have any clue how to do it.

I've tried to create a custom major-mode, but doing that killed all the syntax colors and indentation rules. Ideally what I'd like to do is just modify the nxml mayor mode indentation rules? Still, I don't know where about this rules are.

Also it would be a bonus if I could color some key words, like 'if' or 'set'.

I know that what I'm asking is a big job, so I'm not asking for a definitive answer here. I'm just looking for some help to point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way to do it is writing a new major mode for the language inside the tags and then using [a multiple major modes package](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes) which allows more than one major modes to be active in the same file, so the contained language can have its own major mode.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at this example.

```
(defun nxml-extra-space-indent ()
  (nxml-indent-line)
  (when (zerop (current-indentation))
    (indent-line-to 4)))
(setq indent-line-function 'nxml-extra-space-indent)
```

I indent according to an existing major mode, and then customize the indentation if the line matches certain criteria.
I think this is the easiest way to customize indentation, as you are starting from something existing, and you don't need to know how the indentation logic of a particular mode is implemented.

Comment: I like your idea. I definitely prefer calling a custom function to indent the buffer rather than messing around with major modes. I'm going to work in a function that, if the line contains 'if(' then indent the lines underneath until the line containing the matching parenthesis... Not an easy task for me as I don't know much elisp. we'll see how far can I go :-)

Comment: This page contains most regex functions you are likely to need http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Search.html  There is also a nice macro save-excursion which returns your point to the previous position (ex. after a search). For custom fontification have a look at documentation for font-lock-add-keywords

Comment: That should get you started :)